# Group_concat - query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

This is my SQL operation:

```
select `id_ifc_espaces`,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `nom_espace`) as   nom_espace ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `fonction_espace`) as fonction_espace, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `id_ouvrage_slab_wall`) as id_ouvrage_slab_wall , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `type_limit`) as type_limit,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `type_ouvr`) as type_ouvr from `relespouv` group by`id_ifc_espaces`
```

This is Query Builder that I tried:

```
$relations = DB::table('relespouv')
->select('id_ifc_espaces')
->group_by('id_ifc_espaces')
->where('id_mn','=',$idmn)
->get(array(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nom_espace) as   nom_espace,
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fonction_espace) AS fonction_espace,
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_ouvrage_slab_wall) AS id_ouvrage_slab_wall,
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_limit) AS type_limit, 
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_ouvr) AS type_ouvr ')));
```

When I try to use for example `nom_espace`:

```
 $relespouv[$allelement['Relation']][12]=$relation->nom_espace;
```

I get the error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$nom_espace

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move

```php
array(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nom_espace) as   nom_espace,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fonction_espace) AS fonction_espace,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_ouvrage_slab_wall) AS id_ouvrage_slab_wall,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_limit) AS type_limit, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_ouvr) AS type_ouvr ')
)
```

from `get()` to `select()` like this

```php
$relations = DB::table('relespouv')
    ->select(array(
        'id_ifc_espaces'
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nom_espace) as   nom_espace,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fonction_espace) AS fonction_espace,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_ouvrage_slab_wall) AS id_ouvrage_slab_wall,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_limit) AS type_limit, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_ouvr) AS type_ouvr ')
    ))
    ->group_by('id_ifc_espaces')
    ->where('id_mn','=',$idmn)
    ->get();
```